# Display Excel file in R Shiny

Tags: r, excel, pdf, shiny, display

I am trying to display an excel file using R shiny. I couldn't manage to get the cell colors from the excel. How can I do it? Here is an examples excel file [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/git9p.png). Also, I tried to convert it into a pdf file then display it but still couldn't get the colors. Can you help me with this issue, please?

Comment: You can read it in using `readxl`, `openxlsx`, or `openxlsx2` (to name a few), then use a "fancy table" rendering with `DT`, `kableExtra`, `gt`, or perhaps others that do such a thing.